# Is DNS skipped if I enter the IP Address instead of a URL?

Tags: url, networking, dns

This is my current understanding:

1. I type in a URL (www.google.com) and hit enter
2. The browser checks the cache for a DNS record to find the corresponding IP address of the URL.
3. Once the IP Address has been found a connection is established, and so on...

My question is, what happens if I type in the IP Address directly? Will the browser still attempt to find a DNS record or contact the Domain Name System?

*I believe that the browser will recognise it is an IP address and skip the DNS lookup, but I am not 100% sure about how all this works.*

Is there a way to track in real-time what happens once I hit enter after typing in a URL?

Comment: Generally not. There will usually be a reverse DNS lookup, to establish the host name. This is required for example in HTTPS.

Comment: @user207421 can you explain or give a reference about this reverse query and the relationship with HTTPS? Because I do not think this is the case...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek HTTPS incorporates hostname verification. The hostname is embedded in the server certificate, and the client is obliged to check that against the hostname he thought he was connecting to. *Ergo* a reverse DNS lookup is required if the user provides an IP address.

Comment: @user207421 "HTTPS incorporates hostname verification" yes, if you have an **hostname** in the URL obviously. You are not proving anyrthing nor providing source of your claims. Look at many websites, there is absolutely no reverse DNS entry for them. And do you know about HTTPS virtual hosting? Where multiple names resolve to the same IP... so how your claimed practice would work then?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek 'Yes, if you have a hostname in the URL'. What is *your* source for that assertion? Doesn't say that in RFC 2818 #3.1, only 'if the hostname is available', and one way to make it available if missing is a reverse DNS lookup. I can also imagine a proxy configuration wanting a hostname to see if it should be bypassed.

Comment: @user207421 you started to claim something and not providing any source nor explaining how your supposed scheme works in HTTPS virtual host. So i will stop here. But read the very own thing you quote: "In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
   hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
   in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.". Nothing about reverse DNS or matching names...

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the DNS, when you browse the web as you seem to imply, is to translate a name to an IP address so that the program knows where to connect to.

Hence, by definition, if you give it an IP address to start instead of a name, there is nothing more to translate, and hence the DNS is not needed.

Note however that browsing based on an IP instead of a name may not work as intended, especially in HTTPS land but even in HTTP. This is because the name is not just in the URL but percolates far below, at the TLS level (through the SNI extension to allow virtual hosting in HTTPS on a single IP) and at the HTTP(S) level with the `host` header.

If you want to assess more what is happening in your specific case (as the above is generic, all rules have exceptions) you can either:

- install a local recursive DNS resolver you control, point your OS at it and look in logfiles to see names that have been asked for, or any other queries
- run at the same time a network capture, like with Wireshark, but note that it may be more or less difficult to interpret, specifically if you have a lot of other traffic at the same time. If your OS uses DNS over TLS or DNS over HTTPS, then the network traces will be even harder to understand.

Comment: What is your source for these assertions?

Comment: @user207421 which one? The fact that the DNS translates names to IP addresses in this case? Look at RFC 1034 or 1035 for starters. About SNI, look at RFC 6066 section 3. For HTTP `host` header this can be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields  For a local recursive nameserver look at unbound for example. For DNS over TLS look at RFC 7858 and for DNS over HTTPS this is RFC 8484. Anything else you need?

Comment: @user207421 And we are still waiting for any source going into the same way as your claim in comment that reverse DNS is required by HTTPS. Please share!

Answer (score 0):

This depends *entirely* on the browser you're using.

If you want to see what happens, set up a network sniffer like Wireshark, and you can see what requests go out from your machine to, for example, a DNS or web server.

Assuming you *use* an external DNS server, the presence of a query to it before the actual webpage request will tend to indicate whether or not a direct IP address is used as-is rather than being looked up.

No guarantees on that of course, there are hundreds of different ways to write or configure software<sup>(a)</sup> but this will most likely give you the best indication.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Some so bizarre or torturous that even *I* probably can't envisage them :-)